# How to have network sharing between a lan to wan Firewall Setup?

Tags: firewall, router, local-area-network

I have a Dlink Router wherein one its LAN ports are connected to a Gajshield Firewalls wan port.

The firewall has a Static Wan IP assigned to it from the Dlink LAN network. There is a inbound policy on the Firewall that allows to accept any incoming connections from the Dlinks network only. I have put a static route from the Dlink's network to the Gajshields LAN network.

The thing is that I can ping/http/web to the Gajshield's internal network across its wan interface from the Dlink's LAN but I cant figure out how to conduct sharing between the two networks.

Any suggestions on how to go about it?

Regards

UserCPU

Comment: "How to conduct the sharing?" I may help you as long as I understand what you're looking for! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marco,, Well I want computers on the LAN of the Dlink Network (192.168.4.0) to see & access the computers on the Gajshield 's Internal network (192.168.15.0.) The Dlink' s lan is connected to the Gajshields wan port.

Comment: That would make almost a nonsense to have the firewall there! You would have to configure a complex stateless ruleset to have this goal and keep a minimum of security in the LAN beyond the firewall. I suggest you to buy a managed switch such as Cisco SG-300 (10 to 52 ports available) and have lans separated using VLANS, and both BEYOND the firewall. If there's a reason not to do so, but keep your actual network design please explain why. Glad to help. M.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to have two separate networks, one in front of the firewall and beyond the dlink and another one beyond both. And more, you want them to comunicate? It's kinda a weird design. What's your goal? If you explain what is the purpose of such a configuration i may even agree with you, I'm a flexible guy. But until now I still don't see the point of such a setup.

Comment: Well Actually the Dlink router is having a dmz ip setup, this ip being the WAN ip of the Gajshield Firewall... We have ISP ---> Dlink DSL Router (with NAT) its LAN port -----> WAN port Gajshield Firewall ---> Internal Network (WindowsServer)
On the Firewall the policy is setup to accept incoming connections from Dlink's Network & not from any wan, so this wouldnt actually make anybody have access from outside the office. My intention is to share a folder on the Server & access it from Dlinks lan network.. since I can rdp to the server using private LAN ip like 192.168.15.XX

Comment: Actually the Dlink network is in a office & gajshield network is in a Server Room which is intended to be separated for the organsation I work.. but I need to have an access only for myself from the server room. so that I can Share & RDP to private lan 192 addressess

Comment: @[user182437](https://serverfault.com/users/279765/user182437), could you maybe update your question to reflect the details/info you give in comments? The question as it is now is a little difficult to understand, and re-writing it to add extra details might help get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup you want to address is vulnerable to source routing attacks. 
[Read](http://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/11/en-US/Content/en-US/intrusionprevention/source_route_attacks_about_c.html)
Someone WILL be able to access from the outside right into your server  using the rules you've set up for the office network, unless you buy a dsl modem with a good built in firewall that allows you to filter out from the outside such s**t and as far as I know there's no cheap dlink modem able to do so. Then, if you need to buy some hardware of business level, once again I suggest you to purchase a managed switch and address your goal using VLANs. 
The firewall will be configured to drop everything but what you need from the outside and you'll keep LAN and DMZ separated in the right-and-non-vulnerable way.

Please edit your question adding answers to my questions in the comments in order for the community to take advantage of your fully explained question.

Comment: Ok got it i shall change the rules accordingly & consider the vlans as the basis for the setup..  I think a VPN would be a better option then for such cases.. since for the Gajshield network the dlink network is like a Internet(WAN).

Comment: @user182437 a vpn built into the firewall (and no rules to allow dlink's net incoming) would be a much better choice than your actual setup.

Comment: Right .... I have actually removed those policies on the firewall.. So I shall follow your advice.... Thanks a Lot.......